# Schedule Task with schtasks

Tags: powershell, gpo, windows-task-scheduler

I created a script that creates a scheduled task `GPUpdate /Force` to be executed from a Windows server machine to a Windows 10 machine "Beta" but the script is not executed and an error shows up:

> starttime is not valid

Below you will find my script:

```
schtasks /Create /S Client.Admin.6NLG-AD /U Admin.6NLG-AD\Beta /P ******** /SC MINUTE /MO 1 /TN Update /TR "GPUpdate /Force" /ST defaults
```

Comment: `/st` specifies a start time. `/st defaults` is invalid since `defaults` is not a time. You should be able to just leave out this parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your help but it shows me after that the request is not supported